# External href does not open while fetching from data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In my header i want two adds and site logo in middle. i have place one marquee and one picture add. In marque i have to fetch data from my table. When i click image to go to its URL. It always find page in my domain folder. and do not go to complete URL. java script is used now picture add go to the complete URL but marquee find page in my domain folder. Here is my code:

```
<td width="140" height="140" valign="top"  align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="index-unwel" ><marquee direction="right" scrollamount="2"  onmouseover="this.stop();"   onmouseout="this.start();">
            <div align="left" style="width:94%;">
            <span style="text-transform:uppercase;">  
              <?
                $qryAdv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TOPADD." WHERE 1");
                if(mysql_num_rows($qryAdv) > 0)
                {
                    while($adv = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryAdv))
                    {
              ?>
             <a href= "#" onClick="window.open('<?=$adv['adv_url']?>', '_blank')"><img src="<?=TADD.$adv['adv']?>" width="20%" alt="ADDS"></a> <br /> <br />

              <?
                    }
                } else { echo 'NO ADDS FOUND!!!'; }
              ?>
              </marquee></td>
    <td width="50%" align="center"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo1.gif" width="315" height="140"  alt="LOGO COMPANY" ></a></td>
    <td width="25%" align="center"><a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.veinstitution.com/', '_blank')"><img src="images/veins.gif" width="140" height="140"  alt="LOGO COMPANY" ></a></td>
  </tr>
```

when i click on marquee image it goes to http://divya.veinstitution.com/http//www.veinstitution.com  but it should go to  http//www.veinstitution.com

Adding add to marquee code is:

```
<?php
    include_once("../init.php");
    validation_check($_SESSION['UID'], SITE_HOME_ADMIN);

    $msg='';
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $upDir ='../'.TADD;
        $insertSql="INSERT INTO ".TOPADD." SET 
            `adv_url`           = '".realStrip($_POST['adv_url'])."'";
        $query = mysql_query($insertSql);
        $adv_id = mysql_insert_id();
        $adv = '';
        if($_FILES["adv"]['name']!= ''){
            $fileData  = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["adv"]["name"]));
            $adv = $adv_id . '_adv.' . $fileData ['extension']; 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["adv"]["tmp_name"], $upDir . $adv);
        }
        $upSql="UPDATE ".TOPADD." SET `adv` = '".$adv."' WHERE id = '$adv_id'";
        $query = mysql_query($upSql);

        $msg = '<h3>Record Saved</h3>'; 
    }

?>
```

See and advice me the changes.

Comment: Just an advice, you shouldn't be using `<marquee>` anymore as it is an obsolete feature. It won't work in some browsers anymore. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#the-marquee-element

Comment: what should i use to display adds Is slide show or any other to display adds please suggest

Comment: Plugins like this one: http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples

Comment: ok thanks. Now what about my  problem sir ji

Comment: What do you get inside your window.open in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your URL is missing a colon `:`

`http//www.veinstitution.com` must be `http://www.veinstitution.com`

Hence the browser is appending the base URL because you're using the wrong protocol.

Comment: i can not understand  missing a : means

Comment: it's missing a "colon" symbol after the word `http`

Comment: I was getting confused from 2 hours. Thanks for solving the problem.